# How to preserve comments when minifying files?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-elixir

How could one configure the preserveComments option when minifying assets (running gulp --production)? Is this something that we need to configure somewhere in the Elixir configuration files? Thanks!

Comment: The entire idea of minifying files is to drop any excessive data, like comments. You should always keep a copy of the "full" file in your project repository for developers, but comments don't add any value in production environments (where your minified files should primarily reside).

Comment: I want to leave the license comments though... gulp-uglify has that option for some reason no? It should be possible to configure this like other options.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a suitable answer to this question, so I ended up changing one line in the following laravel-elixir file:

/node_modules/laravel-elixir/tasks/scripts.js

line 69:

`.pipe($.if(config.production, $.uglify({compress: { drop_console: true }})))`

TO

`.pipe($.if(config.production, $.uglify({compress: { drop_console: true }, preserveComments: 'license'})))`

Then run:

gulp --production

**Note**: instead of `license` value for the `preserveComments` option you can use any other described in the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify